# Best known bound on feedback arcset in high-girth directed graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science

Let $G$ be a directed graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges such that every directed cycle in $G$ has length at least $m/k$. An arcset of $G$ is defined as a set of edges $X$ whose removal from $G$ leaves an acyclic graph. What is the best known bound on the size of the smallest such $X$? The best I have been able to find in the literature is a bound $|X| \leq O(k \log k \log \log k)$ due to Seymour (see 1.4 here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01200760 ).

Meanwhile, the best known worst-case lower bound is $|X| \geq O(k \log k)$, which can be obtained by taking an  undirected expander graph and orienting the edges appropriately. Has this gap of $\log \log k$ been closed?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/46518/5038, https://mathoverflow.net/q/355481/37212.  Please don't cross-post.